# How to add and access files to IPFS CLUSTER hosted on AWS FARGATE services?

Tags: blockchain, ipfs

Here is the command I am using to add to files to my IPFS CLUSTER using CLI but I want to connect it to my backend i.e django backend.

```
 ipfs-cluster-ctl -l /dns/d3a323gq69ki35.cloudfront.net/tcp/443 --secret ${SECRET} --basic-auth ${LOGIN:PASSWORD} add ${FILEPATH}
```

Comment: does this mean you want to run that command against the container running in Fargate? You need to provide more info.

Comment: Exactly, Actually I hosted my IPFS CLUSTER on AWS FARGATE using this docs provided by  AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploying-ipfs-cluster-using-aws-fargate-and-amazon-efs-one-zone/ 
They have give me two endpoints by which I can add and access my files in CLI and they working perfect. But I want to take this whole process to my django backend, I even tried all libraries to interact with IPFS from python or Node.js but doesn't work out. Any IDEA???

Comment: With Fargate container you can interact like with any other container. If you want to execute commands, you have to do it from within the container. But AWS won't let you access the container. So you can do `aws ecs exec...`, which allows you to do exactly that. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html